# Keep table data, after SELECT

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

so i use the following query alot

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[date]
      ,[pcknum]
      ,[pcktype]
      ,[pckinfo]
      ,[pckuptime]
      ,[pckbyte]
      ,[pcktext]
  FROM [dbo].[RawLog]
  where pcktext like '%USER SC%' and pckinfo = 174 and not (pcktext like '%type=Dial%' or pcktext like '%type=VoicemailCollect%')
  order by date desc
```

problem is, the table contains more then 10 mio rows, and takes about 20-40 minutes to search trough, and it consumes alot of time.

The table is only accessed by direct user input, as it is used to reverse engineer som network protocols.

i was wondering, if there was a way to make a saved state, of a SQL query, to reduce search times?

for instance a saved state of the query

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[date]
      ,[pcknum]
      ,[pcktype]
      ,[pckinfo]
      ,[pckuptime]
      ,[pckbyte]
      ,[pcktext]
  FROM [dbo].[RawLog]
  where pcktext like '%USER SC%' and pckinfo = 174
```

that i could later on, use queries on?

for instance

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[date]
      ,[pcknum]
      ,[pcktype]
      ,[pckinfo]
      ,[pckuptime]
      ,[pckbyte]
      ,[pcktext]
  FROM table_savedstate_of_RawLog_USERSC
  where not (pcktext like '%type=Dial%' or pcktext like '%type=VoicemailCollect%')
  order by date desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use temp tables for this

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[date]
      ,[pcknum]
      ,[pcktype]
      ,[pckinfo]
      ,[pckuptime]
      ,[pckbyte]
      ,[pcktext]
  into #temptable
  FROM [dbo].[RawLog]
  where pcktext like '%USER SC%' and pckinfo = 174 and not (pcktext like '%type=Dial%' and pcktext like '%type=VoicemailCollect%')
  order by date desc
```

By this you can access the details that are already queried in the `#temptable`

for example

```
Select * from #temptable where id = 1
```

You can also index your temptable for better searching when using it

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_ID ON #temptable(id)
```

Hope this helps :)

****EDIT**

To use the temptable based on your query above

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[date]
      ,[pcknum]
      ,[pcktype]
      ,[pckinfo]
      ,[pckuptime]
      ,[pckbyte]
      ,[pcktext]
  FROM #temptable
  where not (pcktext like '%type=Dial%' or pcktext like '%type=VoicemailCollect%')
  order by date desc
```

Comment: thanks, this was just what i needed, it saved me alot of CPU time :)

Comment: @Droa don't forget to mark it as answer to help also other people, be sure to index your `#temptable` for faster searching